# how to use window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, url-rewriting

I have tried to use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabbed_navigation li").click(function(){
        $class = $(this).attr('id');
        $class="menu/"+$class;
        console.log($class);
        window.history.pushState("url", "Title", $class);
    });
});
```

by using this, the URL will update in the first time

mysite.com/menu/idname

but from second time onwards it works like this

```
mysite.com/menu/menu/idname
mysite.com/menu/menu/menu/idname
mysite.com/menu/menu/menu/idname
mysite.com/menu/menu/menu/menu/idname
mysite.com/menu/menu/menu/menu/menu/idname
```

how can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your code with this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".tabbed_navigation li").click(function(){
        $class = $(this).attr('id');
        $class="/menu/"+$class;
        window.history.pushState("", "","http://"+document.domain+$class);
    });
});
```